In the definition of Nagata dimension, why does it not matter if we stipulate that the cover is open?
To say that the Nagata dimension of a metric space $(X,d)$ is $n$, $\dim_N X = n$, means that there is some $c>0$ such that for every $s$, there exists a $cs$-bounded cover with $s$-multiplicity at most $n + 1$.
What if we ask that the cover be open? Clearly if it satisfies this condition with an open cover then it has the correct Nagata dimension, but what about the other direction? Is there some way, given a $cs$-bounded cover with $s$-multiplicity $k$, to produce a $\bar{c}s$-bounded open cover with the same $s$-multiplicity, possibly with $\bar{c}\neq c$?
This is my first post, sorry if it is bad

Hi and welcome to MSE! I think this question would benefit from more definitions: I'm not sure how many people here are familiar with what $cs$-bounded cover means, or what you mean by $s$-multiplicity.

A cover ${U_i}$ is $cs$-bounded if the diameter (i.e. $\sup_{x, y \in U_i}d(x, y)$) of every set in the cover is at most $cs$. The $s$-multiplicity of a cover is the smallest $n$ such that any set of diameter $\leq s$ meets at most $n$ elements of the cover.
